# Divide the number to a correct decimal

Tags: php

So I have a string like this:

```
000000000050000
```

The last two characters should always be the decimals.

So the end goal here is:

```
500.00
```

I've been trying with substr to take the last two characters, split them off and then divide in to decimals by multiplying, it's not working and seems awfully complicated anyway.

Something like this:

```
$number = substr($str, 2, -2);

$number/500;
```

How can I reach the end goal, presented in the top.

Comment: Why are all those zeros in the front?

Comment: I don't understand why you divide by 500, but the easiest way is surely `substr($str, 0, -2) . '.' . substr($str, -2)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `number_format`:

```
$str = "000000000050000";
echo number_format($str / 100, 2, ",", ".");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)** to get a number out of the string, and **[`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)** to format it properly.

```
$str = "000000000050000";
$int = intval($str, 10); //Base 10, because numbers starting with 0 are automatically considered octal!
$result = number_format($int / 100, 2);
```